# What is the environ.dll?

Tags: assembly, dll

In the following assembly line

```
MOV EDX, DWORD PTR DS: [_environ_dll]
```

I search the environ.dll but I did not find anything which can be useful.

So my question would be: Is there somebody who knows that DLL and explain it in some sentences for me? E.g. the behaviour, the purpose etc.

Or if it is possible some good links maybe, because I did not find any...

edit: the only link which I found so far is

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: There it's just a symbol name, it's not a dll as such. Maybe whatever code you are looking at can use multiple dlls for environment (whatever that is) and it stores a handle in that variable.

Comment: The C runtime not uncommonly has a global "environ" variable.  It is a pointer to the program's environment variables.  The CRT not uncommonly is a DLL so that multiple modules in a program can shared the same runtime state.  The actual name of such a shared variable, after the C pre-processor is done with it, may well be "environ_dll".  The leading underscore is standard C compiler name decoration.  I'd guess at an early Microsoft CRT.

Comment: ah, ok. Thanks. Now I have found : https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man5/environ.5.asp . This is the same what you have written.